# how to calculate product of eigenvalues of matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, eigen

As mentioned in the title. Could anyone teach me to calculate the product of eigenvalues of a matrix? It is ok to use any R function or package. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the results of this search: [`[r] eigenvalue matrix`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+eigenvalue+matrix) will help

Comment: Any question in general should have at least an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please inform yourself on how to ask a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducable example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

How much effort did you put into solving this one yourself?
It's very basic to calculate the product of the eigenvalues of a matrix.
I'll leave the explanations for you to find in the documentation files `?matrix`, `?eigen`, and `?prod`.

```
> m <- matrix(rnorm(25, 5, 10), 5, 5)
> m
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,]  -6.068987  5.657092 16.106767 11.701708  6.060705
[2,]   2.574272  7.420419  9.871342  6.049024 -5.930012
[3,] -10.549236 23.885948 -7.187153  9.084914 -4.843331
[4,]  17.815534  3.348587  1.925881 -3.900034 10.506535
[5,] -10.143544 13.401505 11.022406  5.437238 17.646310

> eigen(m)$values
[1]  20.720634+0.000000i -15.994616+9.683080i -15.994616-9.683080i
[4]   9.589576+6.645961i   9.589576-6.645961i

> prod(eigen(m)$values)
[1] 986078.9-0i
```

Answer (score 0):

`??eigenvalue` points you to `eigen()`. Reading the help page via `?eigen` tells you how to extract the eigenvalues (instead of the eigenvectors). Interestingly enough, `??product` does *not* point you to `prod()`, but now you know about this function. So:

```
> foo <- matrix(runif(9),3,3)
> prod(eigen(foo)$values)
[1] -0.07673157
```